# 'cannot find symbol' with Lucene

Tags: java, import, lucene

I was using the 1.4.3 version of Lucene, but i need to use the 8.11.2 now.

The problem is that some of the import completely changed (from the 1.4.3 version):

```
- import org.apache.lucene.search.Hits;
- import org.apache.lucene.store.InputStream;
- import org.apache.lucene.store.OutputStream;
- import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Token;
```

And i don't find anything when searching on all classes of the 8.11.2 version...

```
[ERROR] /D:/Dev/7.xx/Webtools/hra-tools-web-tools/hr-documentation-tool/src/main/java/com/hraccess/hradoc/edition/HelpAgregator.java:[20,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Hits
[ERROR] location: package org.apache.lucene.search
[ERROR] /D:/Dev/7.xx/Webtools/hra-tools-web-tools/hr-documentation-tool/src/main/java/com/hraccess/hradoc/fts/FtsLuceneApplet.java:[18,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Hits
[ERROR] location: package org.apache.lucene.search
[ERROR] /D:/Dev/7.xx/Webtools/hra-tools-web-tools/hr-documentation-tool/src/main/java/com/hraccess/hradoc/fts/FtsLuceneApplet.java:[28,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Hits
[ERROR] location: class com.hraccess.hradoc.fts.FtsLuceneApplet
[ERROR] /D:/Dev/7.xx/Webtools/hra-tools-web-tools/hr-documentation-tool/src/main/java/com/hraccess/hradoc/fts/RODirectory.java:[70,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class InputStream
[ERROR] location: package org.apache.lucene.store
[ERROR] /D:/Dev/7.xx/Webtools/hra-tools-web-tools/hr-documentation-tool/src/main/java/com/hraccess/hradoc/fts/RODirectory.java:[72,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class OutputStream
[ERROR] location: package org.apache.lucene.store
[ERROR] /D:/Dev/7.xx/Webtools/hra-tools-web-tools/hr-documentation-tool/src/main/java/com/hraccess/hradoc/fts/RODirectory.java:[205,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class OutputStream
[ERROR] location: class com.hraccess.hradoc.fts.RODirectory
[ERROR] /D:/Dev/7.xx/Webtools/hra-tools-web-tools/hr-documentation-tool/src/main/java/com/hraccess/hradoc/fts/RODirectory.java:[213,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class InputStream
[ERROR] location: class com.hraccess.hradoc.fts.RODirectory
[ERROR] /D:/Dev/7.xx/Webtools/hra-tools-web-tools/hr-documentation-tool/src/main/java/com/hraccess/hradoc/fts/RODirectory.java:[285,35] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class InputStream
[ERROR] /D:/Dev/7.xx/Webtools/hra-tools-web-tools/hr-documentation-tool/src/main/java/com/hraccess/hradoc/fts/analysis/cjk/CJKTokenizer.java:[22,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Token
[ERROR] location: package org.apache.lucene.analysis
[ERROR] /D:/Dev/7.xx/Webtools/hra-tools-web-tools/hr-documentation-tool/src/main/java/com/hraccess/hradoc/fts/analysis/cjk/CJKTokenizer.java:[105,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Token
[ERROR] location: class com.hraccess.hradoc.fts.analysis.cjk.CJKTokenizer
```

What can i do to replace these import on the actual 8.11.2 version ?

Comment: Simply replacing the imports is probably not possible. Instead, you will almost certainly need to refactor your code, given there have been many changes (and breaking changes) to the API from your old (ancient!) version to 8.11.2. I recommend you look at the source code provided in the [Basic Demo](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_11_2/demo/overview-summary.html#overview.description). So, for example, you will see code such as `ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;`, and so on.

Comment: You can also find additional up-to-date (for version 8) code examples in the API documents - for example, in the "Description" section of the [analysis package](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_11_2/analyzers-common/index.html). Another approach is to search through the [change logs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_11_2/changes/Changes.html).